# Laptop speakers not working in WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, drivers, speakers

I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 a while back then did a clean install of Windows 10. Since then, I can't get any sound to play through the built-in laptop speakers.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Realtek audio drivers but it hasn't changed anything. The speakers are set to default, and when I open Playback Devices, I can see the audio meter next to the Speakers device jumping up and down, but there is no sound playing. The only other device is the Realtek Digital Output.

If I plug headphones into the audio jack, they work fine. The only reason I know my speakers still work at all is that I can enable an option in BIOS that causes a tune to play when the computer starts (not the normal POST beep), and it plays through the speakers.

It's almost like the audio output is always being redirected to the 3.5mm audio out, whether headphones are plugged in or not.

It's an Asus N55SL laptop.

Comment: Make sure you have drivers from the laptop manufacturers website. Windows may have installed drivers for you after the upgrade.

Comment: I've tried the drivers from the manufacturer (the latest they have are WIndows 7). I've also tried the latest drivers from the Realtek website since they're newer. The headphones work with either but the speakers don't.

Comment: Try installing them in compatibility mode. Right click and go to properties and then the compatibility tab.

Comment: I wasn't sure what compatibility settings you meant, but I tried right-clicking and choosing "Install as Administrator" and that seems to have fixed the problem. I also tried an older version of the driver this time, so maybe that helped. Anyway, thanks! I wouldn't have thought of trying that. If you write it as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Technically you solved it yourself. You can go ahead and answer your own question of you like. Glad I could steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Make sure you include the fact that you are using a Windows 7 driver and include the driver version if you can. People with this same laptop may find this helpful in the future.

Comment: Hey, I used to have this under W7 (pro, NL, x64) on my old Lenovo, I think it was a Thinkpad L512. It was auto-solved with the Windows 10 upgrade though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the speakers working again by downloading an older version of the Windows 7 Realtek audio drivers from the Asus support website. I used driver version V6.0.1.6631.

When installing, I right-clicked the driver setup and said Run as Administrator, which may or may not have helped.